# The stackexchange.com 'sites' page doesn't work without JavaScript

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript, stackexchange.com

If I visit the stackexchange.com *sites* page (https://stackexchange.com/sites) with JavaScript off, I get no content, only the general page headers/footers with a big blank mid-section.

There's also nothing stating you require JavaScript to see the content of the page.

Comment: Just disable styles (CSS), too, and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stack Exchange [All Sites page](https://stackexchange.com/sites) shows a `<noscript>` message now.

Answer (score 1):

<s>[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)</s> [status-canrepro](/questions/tagged/status-canrepro)

Screenshot for everyone else so you don't have to fiddle with settings:

[image]

I can see why it needs JavaScript (though a bare-bones version ought to be easy to add), but they should **at least have a CANHASJAVASCRIPT banner like Stack Overflow.**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Screenshot. I'm not sure if the site will allow me to post one yet as it won't let me do much of anything else (too new). However I don't see why the JavaScript is mandatory for this page - just present a nice text list of all sites. Javascript adds nothing other than an extra click.

Comment: @Jon nice point, added a bit. Yeah, you need <xyz> rep to post images. What most newbied do is use the 'add picture' button, upload it(thru the button), copy the auto-generated link, and link to it. Someone comes along and image-ifies it then.