# Multicollider breaking HTML entities

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-exchange-button, character-escaping

The multicollider seems to have taken upon itself to partially escape apostrophes and break itself:

[image]

Code behind it:
[image]

[The actual comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128385/stackexchange-sites-and-javascript/128387#comment350350_128387) (with code):
[image]

Minor, but it's still a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). OK, it's more of a <sub><sup><sub><sup>[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)</sup></sub></sup></sub>

### Testcases from comment spam below

The "character" referred to is the escaped one.

- Original case: `Thanks for the Screenshot. I'm not sure if the site will allow me to post one yet as it won&#...` (92nd character)
- [This comment:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128439/multicollider-breaking-html-entities#comment350489_128439) `'''''''''''''''''''&#...` (20th character)

Comment: It seems like this will only happen when the apostrophe character is in exactly the right pos I'd wager

Comment: @ConradFrix: Yep. My multicollider did it again on your post.. Feel free to start testing various apostrophe positions here (I don't mind getting my inbox spammed) ;)

Comment: "partially escape apostrophes" seems rather unlikely. The problem is it escapes characters and then truncates for the inbox preview; it should do them in the opposite order

Comment: I noticed this too.

Comment: +1 for the beautiful handwriting on the screenshots

Answer (score 3):

Given that the multicollider does not exist in the current build of our network sites, I cannot reproduce this issue. Please let me know if you experience similar issues with the current top bar.